# How should I put the dataset folder path in this python code

Tags: python, path, gesture-recognition

So I'm working on this sign language gesture recognition python project from git hub.
I followed the read me file and saved (in the project's root folder)  all the dataset files in two seperate folders named as train_videos and test_videos for machine learning.

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
usage: video-to-frame.py [-h] gesture_folder target_folder
video-to-frame.py: error: the following arguments are required: gesture_folder, target_folder
```

Following is the code from "video-to-frame.py" file.
I can't figure out where to put the paths of my data set fodlers.

```
import cv2
import os
import pickle
from os.path import join, exists
import handsegment as hs
import argparse
from tqdm import tqdm

hc = []


def convert(gesture_folder, target_folder):
    rootPath = os.getcwd()
    majorData = os.path.abspath(target_folder)

    if not exists(majorData):
        os.makedirs(majorData)

    gesture_folder = os.path.abspath(gesture_folder)

    os.chdir(gesture_folder)
    gestures = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

    print("Source Directory containing gestures: %s" % gesture_folder)
    print("Destination Directory containing frames: %s\n" % majorData)

    for gesture in tqdm(gestures, unit='actions', ascii=True):
        gesture_path = os.path.join(gesture_folder, gesture)
        os.chdir(gesture_path)

        gesture_frames_path = os.path.join(majorData, gesture)
        if not os.path.exists(gesture_frames_path):
            os.makedirs(gesture_frames_path)

        videos = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
        videos = [video for video in videos if(os.path.isfile(video))]

        for video in tqdm(videos, unit='videos', ascii=True):
            name = os.path.abspath(video)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)  # capturing input video
            frameCount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            lastFrame = None

            os.chdir(gesture_frames_path)
            count = 0

            # assumption only first 200 frames are important
            while count < 201:
                ret, frame = cap.read()  # extract frame
                if ret is False:
                    break
                framename = os.path.splitext(video)[0]
                framename = framename + "_frame_" + str(count) + ".jpeg"
                hc.append([join(gesture_frames_path, framename), gesture, frameCount])

                if not os.path.exists(framename):
                    frame = hs.handsegment(frame)
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                    lastFrame = frame
                    cv2.imwrite(framename, frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
                count += 1

            # repeat last frame until we get 200 frames
            while count < 201:
                framename = os.path.splitext(video)[0]
                framename = framename + "_frame_" + str(count) + ".jpeg"
                hc.append([join(gesture_frames_path, framename), gesture, frameCount])
                if not os.path.exists(framename):
                    cv2.imwrite(framename, lastFrame)
                count += 1

            os.chdir(gesture_path)
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    os.chdir(rootPath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extract Individual Frames from gesture videos.')
    parser.add_argument('gesture_folder', help='Path to folder containing folders of videos of different gestures.')
    parser.add_argument('target_folder', help='Path to folder where extracted frames should be kept.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    convert(args.gesture_folder, args.target_folder)
```

[This](https://github.com/hthuwal/sign-language-gesture-recognition) is the link to project's git hub repository.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm relatively new to python but the snippet of code you shared is a function with inputs of gesture_folder and target_folder so with that said you will need to see where the function convert() is called in your overall code and then check what inputs are inside of the function call.

So if it looks like this then replace the paths in the function call

```
convert("C:\\User\gesturefolder","C:\\User\targetfolder" )
```

But if it looks like this

```
convert(gf,tf)
```

then you will need to work backwards and find where gf and tf are declared and replace the paths there

**EDIT:**

```
parser.add_argument('C:\\User\gesturefolder', help='Path to folder containing folders of videos of different gestures.')
parser.add_argument('C:\\User\targetfolder', help='Path to folder where extracted frames should be kept.')
```

If replacing this with your paths doesnt work then try replacing all backslashes with either \ or /

**EDIT2:**

So I looked through the Github and it appears the paths are provided when calling the python code

```
video-to-frame.py [-h] gesture_folder target_folder
```

Have you tried something like this

```
gesture_folder="C:\\..." #gesture folder path
target_folder="C:\\..." #target folder path

video-to-frame.py [-h] gesture_folder target_folder
```

**EDIT3:**

The last suggestion I can think of is since you are just running it the code directly and not calling it then just define the paths at the beginning of the code between the imports and hc

```
import cv2
import os
import pickle
from os.path import join, exists
import handsegment as hs
import argparse
from tqdm import tqdm

gesture_folder="C:\\..." #gesture folder path
target_folder="C:\\..." #target folder path

hc = []
```

Comment: The function is called in the end of the code snippet I shared already.

Comment: And it's using arguments to input the perimeters to function. I did try putting my folder paths in there but it didn't work :(

Comment: Didnt scroll far enough apparently. I updated my answer. You said you already tried this but have you tried with double backslash or /

Comment: It's still the same. Just when I put the path it says "The following arguments are required: C:\\User\gesturefolder, C:\\User\targetfolder"

Comment: I tried with double slashes, and both forward and backward slashes but of no use

Comment: Just to be clear you replaced it with the actual paths to the folder correct? The ones shown in my code are example paths

Comment: Yes I used the actual paths to the folders.

Comment: About your 2nd edit, where exactly should I put this code? Because I'm directly running the video-to-frame.py file

Comment: Updated answer. If that doesnt work I am not sure how to fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more help... If you end up getting it to work please post the solution here because I'm invested now haha